# How can I fill a single array with a same value? It gives me a an output for a print function

Tags: arrays, c, loops, fill

```
void Array_Fill(int array[], size_t size, int value) {
   if (array != NULL)
   for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
   array [i] = value;
   array[6] = 5.00;
printf("%d,\n", value);
}
```

This is a part of code that should fill an array with desired value for example 7 but it returns same numbers as my print function.

> the output is: Content of array:
> 5,7,15,35,81,51,

> And it should be: Content of array:7 7 7 7 7 7

Comment: First tip: Always use curly braces. There are no bonus points for skipping them.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. IMO your code cannot display what you show.

Comment: [Your code looks working](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gnQVBoLwLUzWMwPC). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The alternative you can  use ```memset()``` declared in ```string.h``` that would do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is pretty weird, the purpose of `array[6] = 5.00;` is unclear, and the usefulness of `printf("%d,\n", value)` is also questionable.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Array_Fill(int array[], size_t size, int value) {
  if (array != NULL)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      array[i] = value;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int ar[10];
  Array_Fill(ar, 10, 7);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("%d ", ar[i]);
}
```

The curly braces in `Array_Fill` could be omitted, but they make the code more readable.