# How can I clear an array and fill it with zeroes?

Tags: arrays, c, file, pointers

```
    if (array != NULL){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; --i){


           {
                int i;
                int array[6] = {5, 7, 15, 35, 81, 51};
                for (i = 0; i < size; --i) {
                 int array[6] = { 0 };
                    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
                }

            }
         }
      }
   }
```

This is my code to clear an array and fill it with zeroes but it seems it doesn´t work I´am using QT creator.

Comment: [`memset()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) is useful to clear arrays to zero. `--i` in your code looks wrong.

Comment: Why aren't you sure if it works or not?

Comment: @ScottHunter I have also other functions implamented in my file but only one works  when i build and run it. It should print all the four functions but it prins only one.

Comment: You have asked a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573315/how-can-i-fill-a-single-array-with-a-same-value-it-gives-me-a-an-output-for-a-p

Comment: To clear array `a`, uses `memset(a, 0, sizeof a);`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  if (array != NULL) {                            // <== array one
>      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; --i) {
>          int i;
>          int array[6] = {5, 7, 15, 35, 81, 51};  // <== array two
>          for (i = 0; i < size; --i) {
>              int array[6] = { 0 };               // <== array three
>              printf("%d\n", array[i]);
>          }
>      }
>  }
> ```

**array one** and **array two** and **array three** are all different and distinct objects. The values in any of them have no relation to the values in any other.

Comment: And also array three `int array[6] = { 0 };` is different.

Comment: As is the third one.